# Is a dual 30A breaker able to serve 30 amps or 60 amps?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Previously I had a 5000 watt King garage heater which turned out to be too small for our new garage. I just bought a 10kw Duraheat garage heater and it keeps tripping. The manual says it uses 42 amps. Is my breaker rated for 30 amps total or 60 amps?
It is a Square DP-4075 common trip  and each pole says 30. The wiring is 6 gauge. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a funny primer on our split-phase system and how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4 Also be aware of NEC 110.3, which requires you to read and follow instructions provided with equipment.  Your instructions would have told you the breaker and wire you needed.  Also note NEC Article 220 about doing a Load Calculation to ensure your service can handle the loads being asked of it.  DIYers frequently get into trouble on this one, especially with EVs.  Speaking of that, if your garage appears to be wired for an EV, you'll get better offers when you sell your house.

Answer (score 9):

A dual 30A breaker can serve 30 Amps, not 60. Fortunately your #6 wire is large enough for a 60 (though some would go with #4).

Answer (score 5):

It's 30 amp total. What's weird is the #6 AWG wiring, which is good for at least 55 amps. You can change out your breaker to whatever the instructions for your heater call for provided it doesn't call for a breaker size that exceeds the wire rating. The instructions always need to be followed.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 different pieces here - current (A), voltage (V), power (W). For a resistive load (like a typical electric heater), W = V x A.

In a standard US setup, V = 120V on a single breaker (120V hot, relative to neutral = 0V) and V = 240V on a double breaker (240V hot to hot, each hot 120V to neutral).

The current rating is based on whatever voltage is used in the breaker. For a single breaker, that is what it says on the label - 30A at 120V. For a double breaker, that really means 30A at 240V. But *technically* it is 2 breakers, each 30A at 120V. Used together (a typical heater circuit) and it is 30A at 240V. Used separately (Multi-Wire Branch Circuit) as two 120V circuits, each gets 30A at 120V. But always the same 30A.

Power - Watts - is what matters in terms of useful work. 30A x 120V = 3,600W. 30A x 240V = 7,200W. 60A x 120V = 7,200W. 60A x 240V = 14,400W. But each of these is derated to 80% for a continuous load. So the available power is based on 80% of the current (24A for a 30A breaker):

- 30A x 120V --> 24A x 120V = 2,880W
- 30A x 240V --> 24A x 240V = 5,760W - That's your old heater at 5,000W
- 60A x 120V --> 48A x 120V = 5,760W
- 60A x 240V --> 48A x 240V = 11,520W - That's your new heater at 10,000W

Because wire size depends on current, it is much cheaper to use 30A (24A useable) x 240V than 60A x 120V. And for the really big loads, you simply can't do it at all with 120V (nobody makes residential 120A x 120V single breakers).

There are some additional complications. Using your new heater which is rated at 42A (which is correct - 42A x 240V = 10,080W), you need a minimum of 42A x 1.25 = 52.5A. So you don't actually need a 60A circuit, you need a 55A circuit. You won't normally find 55A *breakers*, but you will find 55A copper wire - 6 AWG. So your wire is (barely) good enough. The only question is whether you go with a 50A breaker (100% protects the wire, but as I understand it not actually correct here - you upsize normally, not downsize, so 50A would only allow a maximum of 40A continuous according to code, despite the wire size) or a 60A breaker (which is slightly larger than the wire rating, *but* allowed assuming that the panel manufacturer doesn't make an actual 55A breaker).

Comment: I would hesitate to suggest to a member of the public that a breaker whose capacity exceeds that of the wire ever be installed.  Especially since any special instructions required to prevent an electrical fire are highly unlikely to be passed on to the series of future owners of that home.

Comment: @Technophile While in general I agree, in this case I believe code actually allows this combination (55A-rated wire with 60A breaker).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact that may be what code in the United States says, but people in other countries sometimes read the content here.

Comment: So if I install a 50 amp breaker my biggest concern would be tripping occasionally, correct? And if it does trip I can always replace with a 60 amp breaker?

Comment: I *think* so. But be warned: The 55/60 is a special case - in general you absolutely can't "just stick in a larger breaker".